# Usage of extern keyword and multiple translation units

Tags: c++

I am reading Item 4 of Scott Meyer's Effective C++ where he is trying to show an example where  a static non-local object is used across different translation units. He is highlighting the problem whereby the object used in one translation unit does not know if it has been initialised in the other one prior to usage. Its page 30 in the third edition in case anyone has a copy.

The example is such:

One file represents a library:

```
class FileSystem{
    public:
        std::size_t numDisks() const;
    ....
};

extern FileSystem tfs;
```

and in a client file:

```
class Directory {
    public:
        Directory(some_params);
    ....
};

Directory::Directory(some_params)
{
    ...
    std::size_t disks = tfs.numDisks();
    ...
}
```

My two questions are thus:

1) If the client code needs to use `tfs`, then there will be some sort of include statement. Therefore surely this code is all in one translation unit? I do not see how you could refer to code which is in a different translation unit? Surely a program is always one translation unit?

2) If the client code included FileSystem.h would the line `extern FileSystem tfs;` be sufficient for the client code to call tfs (I appreciate there could be a run-time issue with initialisation, I am just talking about compile-time scope)?

**EDIT to Q1**

The book says these two pieces of code are in separate translation units. How could the client code use the variable `tfs`, knowing they're in separate translation units??

Comment: "Surely a program is always one translation unit?" A translation unit essentially consists of a cpp file (source file) plus included files (headers) minus conditional includes (`#if`). So you can have multiple translation units forming a program (they're linked together by the linker in the last translation phase).

Comment: @DyP I do not understand how code can link to other code without a header referring to it?

Comment: You need to have the declaration of a variable / function or the definition of a class in order to use it. You can do that via `#include`, which is essentially copy-pasting the header content into the source file (cpp). The linker matches names declared with extern linkage, like in your example the declaration of `tfs` in any translation  unit to the definition of `tfs` in the translation unit where it's defined.

Comment: @DyP as I understand it using an #include suggests we are within the same translation unit? A translation unit is the source file, coupled with all the header files it #includes to?

Comment: The compiler starts from the input source files. It takes one source file, resolves all the `#include`s and `#if`s and then has a translation unit. Then it continues translating that translation unit. Repeat (independently) for all other source files (-> many TUs). In the end, combine all the translation units (which are object files by now) to form the program.

Comment: Ah ok, so if x.cpp includes x.h and y.h, it doesnt mean y.cpp will be in the same TU as x.cpp? y.cpp could include z.h and would be in a different TU to x.cpp?

Comment: Yes :) It's a bit imprecise to say "a TU is a cpp plus all headers included" or "separate cpp = separate TU" but it's OK here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified example of how initialization across multiple TUs can be problematic.

**gadget.h:**

```
struct Foo;

extern Foo gadget;
```

**gadget.cpp:**

```
#include <foo.h>
#include <gadget.h>

Foo gadget(true, Blue, 'x');    // initialized here
```

**client.cpp:**

```
#include <foo.h>
#include <gadget.h>

int do_something()
{
    int x = gadget.frumple();   // problem!

    return bar(x * 2);
}
```

The problem is that it is not guaranteed that the `gadget`object will have been initialized by the time that `do_something()` refers to it. It is only guaranteed that initializers within one TU are completed before a function in that TU is called.

(The solution is to replace `extern Foo gadget;` with `Foo & gadget();`, implement that in gadget.cpp as `{ static Foo impl; return impl; }` and use `gadget().frumple()`.)

Comment: I repeat my question / comment to Matteo: "It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the first statement of main. **If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.**" Note the word "variable". Please elaborate.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, I understood the problem with multiple TUs- I just didn't understand how a program can be formed of multiple TUs and the part about the extern usage.

Comment: @user997112: My example program is formed of two TUs: gadget.cpp and client.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) If the client code needs to use tfs, then there will be some sort of include statement. Therefore surely this code is all in one translation unit? I do not see how you could refer to code which is in a different translation unit? Surely a program is always one translation unit?

A translation unit is (roughly) a single .cpp file after preprocessing. After you compile a single translation unit you get a module object (which typically have extension `.o` or `.obj`); after all TUs have been compiled, they are linked together by the linker to form the final executable. This is often hid by IDEs (and even by the compilers accepting multiple input files on the command line), but it's crucial to understand that building a C++ program is made in (at least) three passes: precompilation, compilation and linking.

The `#include` statement will include the declaration of the class and the `extern` declaration, telling to the current translation unit that the class `FileSystem` is made that way and that, in some translation unit, there's a variable `tfs` of type `FileSystem`.

> 2) If the client code included FileSystem.h would the line extern FileSystem tfs; be sufficient for the client code to call tfs

Yes, the `extern` declaration tells the compiler that in some TU there's a variable defined like that; the compiler puts a placeholder for it in the object module and the linker, when tying together the various object modules, will fix it with the address of the actual `tfs` variable (*defined* in some other translation unit).

Keep in mind that when you write `extern` you are only *declaring* a variable (i.e. you are telling the compiler "trust me, there's this thing somewhere"), when you omit it you are both declaring it and defining it ("there's this thing and you have to create it here").

The distinction maybe is clearer with functions: when you write a prototype you are *declaring* a function ("somewhere there's a function x that takes such parameters and returns this type"), when you actually write the function (with the function body) you are *defining* it ("this is what this function actually does"), and, if you haven't declared it before, it counts also as a declaration.

---

For how multiple TUs are actually used/managed, you can have a look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731003/214671).

Comment: Nice answer. Maybe you want to add something like "a declaration is a definition unless the name is marked `extern`"?

Comment: @DyP: I usually prefer to see it in reverse: `extern` marks "pure declarations", while "regular" variable definitions contain also an implicit declaration.

Comment: I don't think the last statement is true: "It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the first statement of main. **If the initialization is deferred to some point in time
after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.**" [basic.start.init]/4

Comment: @DyP: isn't that what I'm writing? The initialization can be deferred, and the only guarantee is against the usage of the variable *in the same TU* - if another TU refers to the variable there's no guarantee that it has already been initialized.

Comment: I interpret that differently: "defined in the same translation unit", i.e. before the first use of any _variable in the translation unit of the variable to be initialized_

Comment: @DyP: I don't see how does that change the perspective from another TU... that guarantee refers only to the TU where the variable is defined, while for other TUs there's no such a guarantee.

Comment: See my answer/excerpt from the Standard. IMO, the guarantee applies to all translation units and means "before anything of that TU is used, all variables in there have to be initialized". And using a variable of that TU is "using anything".

Comment: @DyP: aaaah ok, now I got it. I think you are correct, otherwise that would be a guarantee too shallow even for C++. :) Anyhow, I think I'll just remove that, I see that this problem has been debated other times on SO (with no clear conclusion), and the question is about other stuff anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example from the Standard C++03 (I've added the `a.h` and `b.h` headers):

[basic.start.init]/3

```
// a.h
struct A { A(); Use(){} };

// b.h
struct B { Use(){} };

// – File 1 –
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
B b;
A::A(){
    b.Use();
}

// – File 2 –
#include "a.h"
A a;

// – File 3 –
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
extern A a;
extern B b;
int main() {
    a.Use();
    b.Use();
}
```

It is implementation-defined whether either a or b is initialized before main is entered or whether the initializations are delayed until a is first used in main. In particular, if a is initialized before main is entered, it is not guaranteed that b will be initialized before it is used by the initialization of a, that is, before A::A is called. If, however, a is initialized at some point after the first statement of main, b will be initialized prior to its use in A::A.

Comment: Hi (again) I understood the problem of initialisation amongst multiple TUs. What I don't get is how we can have multiple TUs in a single program. If x.cpp includes y.h then they form a translation unit (TU1). So how can another translation unit (TU2) use any code from TU1, unless they use the same headers? If they use the same headers, then surely they're actually not separate TUs?

Comment: Yes they **are** separate TUs, see my comment to your question :)