# C++ visual studio doesn't build properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build, compilation, include

I'm having some serious issues with Visual Studio 2013. I have C++ console project with 2 files: Main.cpp and A.cpp, I'm importing A.cpp with `#include "A.cpp"` in Main.cpp.

Here is the problem: When I edit `A.cpp` and run `Main.cpp`, the changes do not occur. I have to change `Main.cpp` as well and only then will Visual Studio notice the change and recompile everything properly.

This is extremely annoying when I'm trying to change something in `A.cpp`, any idea how to fix this?

**EDIT:**

I have tried renaming `A.cpp` to `A.hpp` and include `A.hpp` from `Main.cpp` with same result: changes to `A.hpp` do not occur in build until I change `Main.cpp` as well. I have tried putting `A.hpp` to both header files and source files in the solution explorer, still the same results.

Comment: Add `A.cpp` into VS project. BTW, unless you know what you are doing, you should never include `.cpp` files into each other. C++ is not Java.

Comment: And how do I add `A.cpp` to the VS project? I see both `Main.cpp` and `A.cpp` in the `Source Files` folder in the Solution explorer.

Comment: @kajacx, do you have `A.h`. If not, then create one and add it. You can show a minimal working example so people can judge what's wrong you're are doing.

Comment: @kajacx That means that `A.cpp` is already included in the project. Do what user @VolAnd suggested and create a corresponding header file `A.h` and include it instead of `A.cpp` in main.

Answer (score 2):

Never do `#include "A.cpp"`! Only `h`-files (or `hpp`) should be included with `#include`. In case you want use in `Main.cpp` some functions defined in `A.cpp` I have to create `A.h` (and do not change `A.cpp`) with declarations of that functions. Of course, you need add both `Main.cpp` and `A.cpp` to project.

**NOTE**: If you add `A.cpp` into VS project and leave `#include "A.cpp"` (not `#include "A.h"`) this will lead to a problem with redefinition of functions from `A.cpp`.

See simple explanation in [C++ forum](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/75734/) and [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730923/create-many-cpp-files-in-one-project)

Comment: He should add it as "C++ header file" (can be changed in file properties).

Comment: Your advice is sound in general. However, there are some cases when you do want to include "cpp" files. I can remember it is used in a technique that lets you implement templates in a "cpp" file: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48575/How-to-define-a-template-class-in-a-h-file-and-imp

Comment: @MarkoPopovic Yes, my answer is quite general, but it is for general question. In any case, thanks for link, perhaps it will be useful for kajacx